# ArcGIS JavaScript API, 403 Forbidden

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to understand the source code of the web application: [NetCDF WMS with n Dimensions](http://dtc-sci01.esri.com/MultiDimWMSViewer/). I tried to run it on my own machine (Mac OS 10.10) and it is run on the Apache. However, I keep getting the error 403 (Forbidden), yet I can't find out the reason.

The application requires a proxy file. I added two lines to let the application know where is the proxy:

```js
function init(){
 initMap();
 /* Here are the two lines code I added */
 esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "proxy/"
 esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
}
//show map on load 
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
```

The error message is:

```
(init.js:157)

GET http://localhost/WMSMultiDimensionalEsriViewer/proxy/?http://sampleserver6.…Dimensional_Sample/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS 403 
(Forbidden)
```

The screenshot is here: 
[image]

Can anyone please point out the issue?

Comment: Do you definitely have a proxy available at `http://localhost/WMSMultiDimensionalEsriViewer/proxy`? You can download the Esri proxy from https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy if necessary

Comment: Thank you so much for response Stephen. Yes, there is two proxy files (proxy.config, proxy.ashx) just came with the application source code in the folder of proxy. I think it's good to try the code in the github. Thank you  for pointing :)

Comment: you could also take a look at the blog post at http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2015/04/07/setting-up-a-proxy/ for detailed instructions

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate of: [ArcGIS Server Setting proxy.ashx with ArcGIS API for JavaScript gives Error 403?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54599/arcgis-server-setting-proxy-ashx-with-arcgis-api-for-javascript-gives-error-403)

> You must add the final destination URL to the proxy.config file for
>   the proxy handler. If you don't, it will respond with a 403 Forbidden
>   code.

Comment: I'm not positive that's the cause, since lower-right section of the Chrome debug tools (in the screenshot) shows the full path to the WMS service